# how to add maven dependency for latest hibernate and spring to pom.xml file?

Tags: maven, dependencies

i have tried.I have right clicked on my project>Maven>Add Dependency but when i search no result is found.
how to automatically update pom file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to search.maven.org.
2. Search for Hibernate and Spring.
3. Copy-paste their dependency declarations.